# install4j installer fails due to missing font packages

Tags: java, installation, java-8, install4j

Hi we have developed Cent OS specific Installer with Install4j this installer is getting failed if created with version 9.0.7, we have licensed copy of version 8.0 if we create installer with this copy it doesn't show the error.

Please find attached error log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(GUIHelper.java:444)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.init(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:83)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.UnattendedScreenExecutor.<init>(UnattendedScreenExecutor.java:51)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.InstallerUnattendedScreenExecutor.<init>(InstallerUnattendedScreenExecutor.java:10)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.getScreenExecutor(Installer.java:80)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.runInProcess(Installer.java:60)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.Installer.main(Installer.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:84)
    at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.start(UnixLauncher.java:69)
    at install4j.Installer293104815.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1349)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1324)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.GUIHelper.invokeOnEDT(GUIHelper.java:440)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.getVersion(FontConfiguration.java:1264)
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.readFontConfigFile(FontConfiguration.java:219)
    at sun.awt.FontConfiguration.init(FontConfiguration.java:107)
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.createFontConfiguration(X11FontManager.java:774)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager$2.run(SunFontManager.java:431)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.<init>(SunFontManager.java:376)
    at sun.awt.FcFontManager.<init>(FcFontManager.java:35)
    at sun.awt.X11FontManager.<init>(X11FontManager.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory$1.run(FontManagerFactory.java:83)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.font.FontManagerFactory.getInstance(FontManagerFactory.java:74)
    at sun.font.SunFontManager.getInstance(SunFontManager.java:250)
    at sun.font.FontDesignMetrics.getMetrics(FontDesignMetrics.java:264)
    at sun.swing.SwingUtilities2.getFontMetrics(SwingUtilities2.java:1125)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.getFontMetrics(JComponent.java:1626)
    at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateMetrics(WrappedPlainView.java:318)
    at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.updateChildren(WrappedPlainView.java:297)
    at javax.swing.text.WrappedPlainView.insertUpdate(WrappedPlainView.java:463)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$RootView.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1610)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler.insertUpdate(BasicTextUI.java:1869)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.fireInsertUpdate(AbstractDocument.java:201)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.handleInsertString(AbstractDocument.java:748)
    at javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument.insertString(AbstractDocument.java:707)
    at javax.swing.text.PlainDocument.insertString(PlainDocument.java:130)
    at javax.swing.text.DefaultEditorKit.read(DefaultEditorKit.java:273)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.setText(JEditorPane.java:1416)
    at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(JEditorPane.java:290)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.createEditorPane(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:360)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.initFontManager(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:320)
    at com.install4j.runtime.installer.frontend.headless.AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.lambda$init$0(AbstractHeadlessScreenExecutor.java:85)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:301)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Java Version of target machine is java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242

Comment: Also if we install urw-fonts and fontconfig using yum install on target CentOS machine it resolves the issue but we can't afford to ship these rpm's and their dependencies with our installer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, some JRE do not work without fontconfig installed, so there is no way to circumvent this error.

Comment: Any specific JRE you suggest that will work without font config

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any insight into that